# Vertically Center Helvetica Neue

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm having trouble vertically centring the font Helvetica Neue. I've used three different popular methods (line-height equal to container, table-cell, padding) which seems to work for many other fonts however Helvetica Neue seems to sit higher than the others. I've placed an example here:

[Font Examples](http://www.kegrunmobile.com/fonttest/)

Are others experiencing the same problems? Or can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Select the lines and you will see the problem. The font in not well done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the font to be vertically centered based on the x-height (the height of the character x) instead of the entire height of the font. Depending on the font and how close the font's size is compared to its container this difference becomes obvious. See [Vertical alignment based on x-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836191/vertical-alignment-based-on-x-height) for my question on how to achieve this in the best way.

My preferred method is to use a `:after` pseudo selector to add an empty container as high as its parent and to use `vertical-align: middle` to vertically center it based on the x-height.

```
.xheight {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.xheight:after {
    content: '';
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I want the font to be vertically centered based on the "T" height like the default and Helvetica are. I tried your solution and it seems to be similar to the other methods, perhaps a little better. I've been mucking around on Android to get more control and it seems like the actual ascent of the font is greater than the ascent that the font reports.