# CSS/HTML Text Not perfectly centring in flex box despite setting appropriate constraints

Tags: html, css, sass

Text Not perfectly centring within the Flex Div despite setting, align-items, justify-content, flex-direction.

It's particularly evident on F and d, the bottom and top should be equidistance from their respective boundaries

[image]

CSS:

```
        .fbubble{
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            &.feat {
                width: 25%;
                margin-top: 3em;
                background: $pink;
                height: 32px;
                h2 {
                    height: 100%;
                    font-size: 20;
                    font-weight: 500;
                    color: $white;
                }
                
            }
         }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="fbubble feat">
        <h2>Featured</h2>
    </div>
```

Edit:

[image]

Comment: I believe this is simply how the font is designed. This might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836191/vertical-alignment-based-on-x-height

Comment: One solution (more of a hack), is to add margin/padding to compensate these fonts. This is the easiest one. Also set the `line-height` a pixel or two less and see if you can live with that.